# Expected value of random variable times indicator function of log normal process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

Given the process $log(A) = \sqrt{\rho}T\sigma Y + \sqrt{(1-\rho)T} \sigma Z^i - \frac{1}{2}T\sigma^2$ find $E[e^{\sqrt{(1-\rho)T}\sigma Z^i}\mathcal{1}_{A<c}]$ where $Z^i \sim N(0,1)$, c and Y are some positive constants, and $\mathcal{1}$ is the indicator function.

The indicator function conditions on process $A$ and the exponential function inside the expectation is a function of $Z^i$ so I am a bit puzzled how to proceed. Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Let's write $\ln A = \alpha + \beta Z^i$ for $\alpha, \beta$ constant and $\beta > 0$. Note that
$$
A < c \iff \ln c > \ln A \iff Z^i < \frac{c - \alpha}{\beta}.
$$

Can you now finish?

**UPDATE**

Let $\phi(z)$ and $\Phi(z)$ denote the pdf and cdf of the standard normal distribution. You have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\beta Z} \mathbb{I}_{A<c}\right]
 = \int_{-\infty}^{(c-\alpha)/\beta} e^{\beta z} \phi(z) dz
$$
which after completing the square you should be able to express as $\Phi(\cdot)$ of some transformation of $\alpha, \beta, c$.

Comment: Rewriting it as $E[e^{\beta Z^i} \mathcal{1}_{Z^i < \frac{c-\alpha}{\beta}}]$ and after completing squares I have $e^{0.5\beta^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{c-\alpha}{\beta}}e^{-0.5*(Z^i - \beta)^2}dZ^i$. What after that?

Comment: @ForumWhiner please see the update

Comment: $A<c \implies Z^i < \frac{c-\alpha}{\beta}$ which means that the upper limit point of integral is $\frac{c-\alpha}{\beta}$ and lower limit point is $-\infty$ isn't it? Why do you have $\frac{c-\alpha}{\beta}$ as the lower limit point in the integral then?

Comment: @ForumWhiner +1, corrected